# After running a query, message of succes action

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to return a success/failure message after running the query and how to check for exist data in `product_code` data array before saving the data?

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `produk2`
(product_code,product_name,product_desc,product_type,product_price,product_img,product_img_name) 
VALUES ('$kod','$namaproduk','$spesifikasi','$jenis','$harga','$image','$name')");
}
```

I tried to run this code and doesn't seems to work. Any ideas? I've gone wrong?

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
  echo "<br/>Data uploaded.";
}
else
{
  echo "<br/>Data not uploaded.";
}
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. should use mysqli_*

Comment: do you have any page/website that is easily to understand on how to use mysqli, i did try to use mysqli but it didnt work for me.

Comment: check out [php mysqli tutorial](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mysql_error()` or `mysql_errno()`.

See the manual

[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Answer (score 0):

Add `if` `else` condition to the return result of query.

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `produk2`
(product_code,product_name,product_desc,product_type,product_price,product_img,product_img_name) 
VALUES ('$kod','$namaproduk','$spesifikasi','$jenis','$harga','$image','$name')");

if($query)
{
    echo "Data inserted";
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry! Data not inserted";
}
```

Comment: thx, it works, but i have something else in my mind that im trying to do, its no as simple as just some pop up message like that sir, after i run the query what i really want is to go to another page to show the succes message, and the question is, how to call other pager after running the query? or can i just add the action="page.php" at form to direct to another page? but how can it check if the data's been save or not?

Comment: just use `if()` in jquery like
`success:function(data)
   { if(data === 'Data inserted'){ window.location.replace(''your uls where you want to nevigate)}
`

Comment: i dont really know how to use jquery, can u give a simple example of the source code? sorry if its too much to ask. really need help to finish my project badly..